# How to use App::before() Laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, middleware

i did a migration from Laravel 4.2 to 5.0, and reading another questions, i created a new *Middleware* on my *app\http\middleware* but, i don't know how implement this to my *RouteServiceProvider.php*

This is my *BeforeMiddleware*:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class BeforeMiddleware {

 /**
  * Handle an incoming request.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @param  \Closure  $next
  * @return mixed
  */
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
    return $next($request);
 }

}
```

And on my *RouteServiceProvider* i got this

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    //I think here need to be my code...    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your middleware in the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file.

Here you will find 3 options:

```
protected $middleware = [..] <-- run on EVERY request

protected $middlewareGroups = ['web'=>...] <-- run on all web routes

protected $routeMiddleware = ['auth'...] <-- run on routes when defined
```

Comment: It was declared on the  _app/Http/Kernel.php_.
Only with that options will work? or i need just something else?

Comment: Yes - these are your options now. The `before` filter was replaced by middleware in Laravel 5.0. You'll probably want to register your middleware for every request, as that's how `before` would have worked for you previously.

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with this same situation some time ago for a CRM, and the ideal approach is to migrate what you had within `App::before()` in **Laravel 4.2** to a service provider in **Laravel 5.0**.

At first you can just use the `boot()` method located in the `AppServiceProvider`, in a way that you can test the waters.

From there you can opt to have a dedicated service provider just to hold this part, such as **AppBeforeServiceProvider**.

You have mentioned a migration to **middleware**, but that is actually for `filters` coming from **Laravel 4.2**.